# Avoiding race condition between Ember.js and other js libraries

Tags: ember.js

I'm having this issue in a handful of places, but most recently it's a problem with Highcharts. I have a layout with three divs, call them #leftdiv, #maindiv, and #rightdiv. There is a highcharts chart in #maindiv. leftdiv and rightdiv can be hidden my clicking a button.

Right now, clicking that button for leftdiv calls an action handler that sets a property called showLeft to false. The classes for the divs are bound to a computer property based on showLeft, as follows:

```
leftClass: function() {
    if (this.get('showLeft')) {
        return "span3"
    } else {
        return "span0" 
    }
}.property('showLeft')
```

and

```
mainClass: function() {
    if (this.get('showLeft') && this.get('showRight')) {
        return "span6"
    } else if (this.get('showLeft') || this.get('showRight')) {
        return "span9" 
    } else {
        return "span11"
    }
}.property('showLeft', 'showRight'),
```

This works to hide the left bar. However, once the size of maindiv changes I need to redraw the highcharts chart to fit the new div.

However, when my redraw chart function observes showLeft it behaves unpredictably, because the properties might update and propagate through the DOM after the observer fires.

Is there some general construct in Ember to allow me to avoid this problem? Is this a situation where expressly building a runloop is called for and is there a canonical way to do it?

Thanks,

--Matt

Comment: Did you try Ember.run.next?

Comment: I did - it seemed that still took place before the render queue

Answer (score 2):

You could try observing the values from the `View`, calling `rerender()`, and using `didInsertElement` to handle repainting the Highchart

e.g.

```
App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    ...
});
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'whatever-template',
    resize_observer: (function() {
         this.rerender();
    }).observes('controller.showLeft', 'controller.showRight'),
    didInsertElement: function() {
        /* Refresh your charts here */
    }
});
```